# nodejs: npm install command shows error

Tags: angularjs, node.js, npm, npm-install

I've install `node.js` in windows and i gave `npm install` command, it is showing following error. I set environment variables.

I gave `npm cache clear` also.

**Error**

```
npm WARN retry will retry, error on last attempt: Error: EBUSY: resource busy or
locked, rename 'C:\Users\RAMYAG~1\AppData\Local\Temp\npm-704-3e1504c0\registry.
npmjs.org\get-pkg\-\get-pkg-0.3.0.tgz.3764799858' -> 'C:\Users\RAMYAG~1\AppData\
Local\Temp\npm-704-3e1504c0\registry.npmjs.org\get-pkg\-\get-pkg-0.3.0.tgz'

npm ERR! Windows_NT 6.1.7600
npm ERR! argv "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\
node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "install"
npm ERR! node v6.9.1
npm ERR! npm  v3.10.8

npm ERR! tarball.destroy is not a function
npm ERR!
npm ERR! If you need help, you may report this error at:
npm ERR!     <https://github.com/npm/npm/issues>
npm WARN retry will retry, error on last attempt: Error: EBUSY: resource busy or
locked, rename 'C:\Users\RAMYAG~1\AppData\Local\Temp\npm-704-3e1504c0\registry.
npmjs.org\date-store\-\date-store-0.1.2.tgz.1345740487' -> 'C:\Users\RAMYAG~1\Ap
pData\Local\Temp\npm-704-3e1504c0\registry.npmjs.org\date-store\-\date-store-0.1
.2.tgz'
npm ERR! Windows_NT 6.1.7600
npm ERR! argv "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\
node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "install"
npm ERR! node v6.9.1
npm ERR! npm  v3.10.8
```

Please help to solve this issue.

Thanks,
Kamal

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://github.com/npm/npm/issues/13461

Please look at the above thread, you may find the solution

Answer (score 0):

If
    npm cache clean

not worked, check if you have an active anti-malware. Some packages are blocked by anti-malware applications.

Answer (score 0):

I tried as @Thamizhselvan said and it worked.
https://github.com/npm/npm/issues/13461
Please look at the above thread, you may find the solution